# Excel VBA code works in Windows 10 but not on MacBook Pro running macOS Catalina 10.15.7 and Excel for Mac Version 16.43

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have some code in an Excel VBA worksheet sub that works perfectly well on Windows 10 devices but not on a MacBook Pro running macOS Catalina 10.15.7 and Excel for Mac Version 16.43.

I've narrowed the code down to these lines:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
    'Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",False)"
    Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "HideRibbon"
    Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False
    'Application.DisplayStatusBar = Not Application.DisplayStatusBar
    'ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = False

End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
    'Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",True)"
    Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "HideRibbon"
    Application.DisplayFormulaBar = True
    'Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    'ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = True
End Sub
```

Can anyone provide any guidance on how to resolve this?

Many thanks in advance.

Fraz

Comment: I think ExecuteExcel4Macro is a legacy bridge to an Excel version that was created before there was an Excel for Mac. So, if you can replace the use of that macro you should have a compatible solution.

Comment: Thx Brax, but that line of code is actually rem'd out. It's only the 2 lines: Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "HideRibbon"
    Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False    which are active currently.

Comment: It's unlikely to be `DisplayFormulaBar`. Therefore it must be `ExecuteMso`. Proceed from the thought that a Mac handles command bars differently from a Windows PC and that, therefore, VBA needs different commands to manipulate them. If such commands exist, a search for "VBA CommandBars.ExecuteMso" may turn them up, perhaps with the asddition "for Mac".